# With CanCan, limit what roles an admin can assign to self or others through AdminAbility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rails-activerecord, rails-authorization

I'm trying to setup a admin role system, where many admins have different roles. I'm starting with two roles, :super_admin and :office_admin.

I want the :office_admin the ability to manage other :office_admins, but not the :super_admins. I've accomplished parts of this idea through the Ability file.

My schema:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admin_assignments
  has_many :admin_roles, :through => :admin_assignments
  attr_accessible :name, :admin_role_ids
end
```

.

```
class AdminAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :admin_id, :admin_role_id
  belongs_to :admin
  belongs_to :admin_role
end
```

.

```
class AdminRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admin_assignments
  has_many :admins, :through => :admin_assignments
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

.

```
class AdminAbility
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(admin)
    if admin.role? :super_admin
      can :manage, Admin
    elsif admin.role? :office_admin
      can :manage, Admin, :admin_roles => { :name => ['office_admin'] }
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is I cannot prevent the office admin assigning himself the role of SuperAdmin. Is this something I can do through CanCan or do I have to push parts of that authorization logic into the ActiveRecord model?